# Finding Buttons On Yahoo Finance using Selenium[JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, yahoo-finance

I was recently trying automatically pull quarterly data from the financial reports found on yahoo finance and could not find a way to do it. I thought I could `click` the `buttons` from the financial home page (E.x https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/financials) but I could not find a way to locate the web elements. First, I need to click the button saying `Balance Sheet`.

Here is all the `HTML` code for this button:

```
<div class="Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) Pend(15px) H(18px)" data-reactid=".27ez98r5x0u.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.2.0.0.0.1.1:$balance.0">
<span data-reactid=".27ez98r5x0u.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-   Quote.2.0.0.0.1.1:$balance.0.0">Balance Sheet
</span>
</div>
```

Next I need to find and click the button reading `Quartely`

```
<div class="Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) Pend(15px) H(18px) C($finDarkLink):h Mend(15px) C($actionBlue)" data-reactid=".27ez98r5x0u.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.2.0.0.0.1.2.$1.0">
<span data-reactid=".27ez98r5x0u.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.2.0.0.0.1.2.$1.0.0">Quarterly
</span>
</div>
```

Any help on locating these buttons or alternative methods to finding this financial information would be helpful.

Comment: Better you can search for some web services if they are providing for same

Answer (score 0):

Find using Xpaths:

```
//button[contains(.,'Balance Sheet')]
//button[contains(.,'Quarterly')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually these buttons are getting ready to click after loading the page, So you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until these buttons are getting visible and ready to click as below :

```
String url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/financials";

driver.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

WebElement balanceSheet = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Balance Sheet']")));
balanceSheet.click();


WebElement quarterly = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Quarterly']")));
quarterly.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any possibility to pull the quarterly balance sheet from yahoo financials through excel VBA. I am trying very hard to extract quarterly Income statement, Balance sheet and cash flow with help of ticker in VBA, I also not able to extract one specific line item for eg: Revenue or net income or Cash and Cash Equivalents etc., I am new to VBA just beginner.

Comment: If you have any problem, then post it as a *Question*. Don't post your problem to posts as an *Answer*.